# Проблема при компиляции С++ перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Помогите решить вот такую проблему. Дан код

```
namespace Math {

namespace Detail {
    template<typename T, uin32_t>          class Vector;
    template<typename T, uin32_t, uin32_t> class Matrix;
}

template<typename T> using Vector2D_tpl = Detail::Vector<T, 2>;
template<typename T> using Vector3D_tpl = Detail::Vector<T, 3>;
template<typename T> using Vector4D_tpl = Detail::Vector<T, 4>;


using Vec2 = Vector2D_tpl<F32>;
using Vec3 = Vector3D_tpl<F32>;
using Vec4 = Vector4D_tpl<F32>;

using Vec2f = Vector2D_tpl<F64>;
using Vec3f = Vector3D_tpl<F64>;
using Vec4f = Vector4D_tpl<F64>;

using Vec2i = Vector2D_tpl<I32>;
using Vec3i = Vector3D_tpl<I32>;
using Vec4i = Vector4D_tpl<I32>;

template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator-(Detail::Vector<T, N> const& rhs)  noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator+(Detail::Vector<T, N> const& lhs, Detail::Vector<T, N> const& rhs)  noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator-(Detail::Vector<T, N> const& lhs, Detail::Vector<T, N> const& rhs)  noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator*(Detail::Vector<T, N> const& lhs, T const& rhs) noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator*(T const& lhs, Detail::Vector<T, N> const& rhs) noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
template<typename T, U32 N> constexpr auto operator/(Detail::Vector<T, N> const& lhs, T const& rhs) noexcept->Detail::Vector<T, N>;
}
```

Код скомпилруется только так

```
using Math::operator+;

Math::Vec2 v1;
Math::Vec2 v2;

v1 + v2;
```

Как сделать чтобы работало и так

```
Math::Vec2 v1;
Math::Vec2 v2;

v1 + v2;
```

Comment: Перенести все операторы в пространство `Detail`, тогда компилятор сможет их найти посредством ADL.

Comment: Да это поможет, но не будет виден доступный интерфейс. Может есть средства которые могут помочь ADL. Хотя может и забить все же знают что вектора задают линейное пространство

Comment: @МихаилГоробец Вы бы привели ошибки компиляции для полноты вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Поместите объявления всех операторов, работающих с типами из `namespace Detail`, внутрь `namespace Detail`. Почему они вдруг у вас оказались на уровень выше?

Comment: ...и тогда их подхватит argument-dependent lookup безо всяких `using`.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте оператор сложения дружественной функцией:

```
namespace Detail {
    template<...> class Vector {
        friend decltype(auto) operator+(const Vector&, const Vector&) { return Vector(); }
    }
}
```

Пример (для наглядности неиспользуемая часть кода удалена):

```
namespace Math {
namespace Detail {

template<typename T, int> 
class Vector {
    friend decltype(auto) operator+(const Vector&, const Vector&) { return Vector(); }
};

}  // namespace Detail

template<typename T> using Vector2D_tpl = Detail::Vector<T, 2>;

using Vec2 = Vector2D_tpl<int>;

}  // namespace Math

int main() {
    Math::Vec2 v1, v2;
    v1 + v2;
    return 0;
}
```